# in app monetization for Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, tapjoy

I am looking for a way to set up a virtual currency in my `Xamarin.iOS` app.

Has anyone set up a virtual currency in their `Xamarin.iOS` app?

If so which provider works well with Xamarin?

Two Providers I know of are [Trialpay](http://www.trialpay.com/) and [Tapjoy](http://www.tapjoy.com/). 
I am not sure if its possible to get their library's to work in `c#` however. Has anyone accomplished this and can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [monotouch bindings](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings) project includes bindings for TapJoy.

Comment: Thanks, any documentation on how to actually use these bindings? I am very new to this.